# Como utilizar atof em C

Tags: c

Poderiam me ajudar a utilizar a função atof? Meu código está dando "access violation" na linha em que estou utilizando atof, ja tentei mudar o tipo do array "dado" tanto para int e float

```
int main() {
char pilha[10];
int i;
int dado[10];
int topo = 0;

printf("Informe a expressao\n");
gets(pilha);
fflush(stdin);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(pilha); i++)
{
    if (isdigit(pilha[i]))
    {
        dado[topo] = atof(pilha[i]);
        topo++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função atof serve pra converter uma string para um double. Strings em C terminam com '\0' e quando você faz atof(pilha[i]) o programa não encontra o '\0', que indicaria que é uma string, e gera esse erro, veja na assinatura da função: double atof(const char *str);
Use a função strtok() para separar sua variável pilha em várias strings de acordo com um padrão de separação, assinatura da função é: char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim), onde char *str é a string que deseja separar e const char *delim é a string que possui o que será usado para fazer essa separação.
Exemplo de uso:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   char str[80] = "Isto eh - um - teste";
   char s[2] = "-";
   char *token;
   /* pega o primeiro token */
   token = strtok(str, s);
   /* caminha através de outros tokens */
   while( token != NULL ){
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Nossa, verdade! Acabei esquecendo que em C para ser string tem que terminar com '\0'. Muito obrigado, Matheus!!!